# Passing huge string from native to java - out of memory error

Tags: android, c++, string, java-native-interface

I am writing a function in native C++ where it returns a big string using `env->NewStringUTF`. The problem is that when the string is big (about 23 Mbytes) I get an out of memory exception in Java.

I already tried getting the data in parts, but it is very slow.

This is my code:

```
char* d = data.c_str();
jstring str = env->NewStringUTF(d);
return str;
```

How can I pass this string to Java?

Comment: Unfortunately, passing big chunks of data through JNI is slow. I have not yet found a way to solve this problem.

Comment: What are you going to do with the string in Java?

Comment: Why do you need such a big string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant keep such a big string in memory. Heap limit on some android devices is 16MB for whole application.

I suggest you to save this string to a file (or maybe in db) and pass file name to java.

Or maybe you should change application logic and continue keeping string in native space and pass to java only small requested parts...

P.S. You can compress string with GZIP and reduce it's memory footprint in several times, but you still wont be able to keep whole decompressed string in java...

Comment: Does sqlite support that size of strings? In any case sqlite has to do the same transfer from native to Java? Am I correct?

Comment: +1 for the GZIP, I thought about it too, but indeed, it does not solve the problem.

Comment: You'll be able to save such string in sqlite, but it will take as much time as saving it to a file (quite a long time, sqlite keeps it's data on file system). So you wont get any speed gains.

Comment: If you don't need query capabilities using a plain file is faster than using a database system, however why do you need such a big string in Java? For example, if you are trying to parse/encode, decode JSON or some other protocol data why not do the parsing in native code.